# Multiple MySQL row INSERT failing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was doing a simple `INSERT` during my development, but I'm going back and putting in SQL protection and prepared statements.  The error I receive is:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: 
>   number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Here is the code that I'm using from help from others on SO.

```
// foreach to set up variables
foreach ($json as $text) {
    $uoid = mysql_real_escape_string($uoid);
    $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($uoid.".jpg");
    $filedate = mysql_real_escape_string($datetime);
    $imagedesc = mysql_real_escape_string($desc);

    // array of values
    $insert[] = array($uoid,$filename,$filedate,$imagedesc);
}

function placeholders($text, $count=0, $separator=","){
    $result = array();
    if($count > 0){
        for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
            $result[] = $text;
        }
    }
    return implode($separator, $result);
}

foreach($insert as $d){
    $question_marks[] = '('  . placeholders('?', sizeof($d)) . ')';
}        

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=photo_gallery;host=127.0.0.1', 'myuser', 'mypass');
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_gallery (" . implode(',', array_values($insert) ) . ") 
        VALUES " . implode(',', $question_marks);
// reading output
echo $sql;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

try {
    $stmt->execute($insert[0]);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$pdo->commit();
```

When I look at the SQL output:

```sql
INSERT INTO wp_gallery (10219776,10219776.jpg,my image description,2012-08-01 15:36:29)
VALUES (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?)
```

Everything matches just by the look of it, but I'm still baffled as to how to fix this.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: and you cannot see the error?

Comment: You need column names. You're putting values there, and not replacing the question marks.

Comment: Please review your questions before providing to community.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure what to expect on the output since I never used prepared statements before.  Instead of down voting why not try to actually help?

Comment: @hybrid9 In case you didn't see, there are 3 answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing values as column names, and you're not passing the correct parameter to execute;

Something like this would be more correct;

```
// Replace the $insert buildup. Array of values, you don't want an array of arrays here.
$insert = array_merge($insert, array($uoid,$filename,$filedate,$imagedesc));

...

$column_names = array("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4");

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_gallery (" . implode(',', $column_names ) . ") 
    VALUES " . implode(',', $question_marks);

$stmt->execute($insert);
```

Comment: Hi, Joachim, thanks for the input. I think I understand what you're saying Joachim, but my original foreach loop ($json) iterates 5 times, so that becomes an array of arrays with those values in $insert[].  I have the columns outputting properly, but I'm still stuck with the '?' in the VALUES.

Comment: @hybrid9 There are supposed to be question marks in "values". You're using PDO, so every question mark in the query gets replaced by a value from the array you pass into execute. One question mark should correspond with one value in the `$insert` array. Did you try the code above? It changes the `$insert` array to be an array of values, one value per question mark, and passes the array into execute.

Comment: I still get an error: VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" } Notice: Array to string conversion....Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: @hybrid9 Sounds like you have less or more elements in the array than you have question marks. Each question marks is replaced with one element of the array, so they need to match. Hard to tell more than that without seeing the actual code you're at now.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO name_of_the_table (name_of_column_1, name_of_column_2,...) VALUES
 (value_of_column_1, value_of_column_2), (value_of_column_1, value_of_column_2);
```

If you set the values of all columns in the order they are defined, you can omit the names of columns.

You however put the values where column names should be and question marks, where values should go.

Answer (score 0):

[INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(111,222),(333,444);](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)